# Is it possible to pass a String parameter to viewModel from Android xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-mvvm

Is it possible to pass a String parameter on a button click of XML file to  the methods of the view model file as like below

```
 android:onClick="@{v -> viewModel.postFeedRequest(@string/show_details)}"
```

I tried like above i am getting binding error.

Can anyone post any example on this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.postFeedBackRequest(AppConstant.WithStringResource)}"
```

where `AppConstant` is your class and `WithStringResource` is your String constant with the value you want to send.

**Update**:

You can also directly send the string like this:

```
android:onClick='@{() -> viewModel.postFeedBackRequest("WithStringResource")}'
```

Or

```
 android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.postFeedRequest(@string/show_details)}"
```

Comment: How to a pass a string xml resource to the method?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this
In viiew model

```
  fun onClickFunction(num:String) {
            edExtnNumber.set(edTextField.get()+""+num)
        }
```

and in xml

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onClickFunction(@string/value)}">
```